# Web scrape (or similar) html code from an ip address via Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently have a Zebra printer which currently has its own IP address. When you visit the ip address via Chrome, it provides you the status of the printer (see attached).

[image]
I am wondering is there a way to

Is there any javascript library (or native code) that people recommend that could do this?

Comment: Since you tagged this [tag:reactjs] I'm going to assume you are talking about JavaScript running client-side in a web browser as a webpage hosting a react application (and close it as a couple of duplicates).

Comment: Note that you can't visit "an IP address" with a web browser, you can visit a URL which happens to use an IP address in the [authority](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3) section.